# Audio tags in React app play wrong audio clips when list of audio clips is filtered

Tags: reactjs, audio, filtering

I'm working on a simple react app that allows playback of a set of mp3 files using the HTML audio tag and filtering of the set of mp3 files to allow the user to find the ones they want to play.

It works fine when no filtering is applied and I see an Audio player for each mp3 file. But when I filter the list of mp3 files, I see a correctly reduced list of audio players but they do not always play the correct file now.

For example, if I have three mp3s - A, B and C - and then I filter to just show B and C I now see two audio players. But they will play A and B, not B and C. And in this case, as A is filtered out, I want the app to show audio elements for B and C that actually play B and C.

I've put together some code in a React sandbox that I hope shows the problem. If you filter the mp3s in the sample app to just show the ukulele sound clip, it still plays the first mp3 when you click the play button.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-5y0bp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I've seen this behaviour now on Chrome, Firefox and Edge. Even on Chrome on iOS.

Any ideas what's going on here? Or how I can prevent or work around this? Am I just missing something glaringly obvious? Any advice welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen the error the appears on the console? `Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`. Please review https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html for more information on how keys help avoid this situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Comment: Oh my god, it's so obvious now you say it. I had keys on them in my own app,even though I forgot them in the sample I provided. But even in my own app, they were not unique enough. It all works now.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky If you can post one of your comments as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I've added an answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your example application emits the following error: `Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`. You would need to add a [unique key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings) to each item returned from `Array.prototype.map()`. This will help "React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed" and in your situation ensure filtering can work effectively. In your case it looks like each URL is unique so perhaps that can be used as an effective `key`:

```
  <div>
    <h1>Filter</h1>
    <input value={this.state.text} onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} />
    <ol>
      {filteredList.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={item}>
            {item} -{" "}
            <audio controls preload="none">
              <source src={item} type="audio/mpeg" />
            </audio>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </ol>
  </div>
```

You can use `index` as a last resort `key`, but it is recommended to avoid using index as key. Otherwise you can use packages like `uuid`, `Date` methods such as `getTime()`, or even something extracted/combined from each url string value to create unique keys when you initialize state or add items to the state array.

Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-tyumy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) in action.